# DataInputStream not reading small files

Tags: java, blackberry, datainputstream

I am programming a blackberry app that reads small files stored on the device. 
For some reason DataInputStream will only read files that are bigger then 3kb (my estimate after a couple of test). Anyone know why this may be the case?

```
try 
{
    fconn = (FileConnection)Connector.open(seedDataLocation);
    if (fconn.exists())
    {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen().add(new RichTextField("Read?: " + fconn.canRead()));
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen().add(new RichTextField("Write?: " + fconn.canWrite()));
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen().add(new RichTextField("Open?: " + fconn.isOpen()));

        int dataSize = (int) fconn.fileSize();
        DataInputStream dis = fconn.openDataInputStream();
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen().add(new RichTextField("Data Available: " + dataSize));
        byte[] b = new byte[dataSize];
        dis.readFully(b);
        String data = new String(b);
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen().add(new RichTextField("Data: " + data));

        fconn.close();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen().add(new RichTextField(e.getMessage()));
}
```

edit: I tried doing dis.available(); and it is returning 0 for small files in which it does not read from the file and also 0 from bigger files it will read from. Which is confusing because it is supposed to read the amount of bytes in the file.

Comment: are you getting some sort of error?

Comment: I am not getting any exceptions thrown when running the app on the device.

Comment: so when you say "it won't read the files", what do you mean?

Comment: As in it does not read the contents in the file and save them into the byte array.

Answer (score 1):

That `getActiveScreen().add` call is error prone, and it will fail if you try to call it from outside the GUI thread. The fact that it is working for you means that you are actually making these calls from the GUI thread, which is horrible practice since you are also opening a file from there.

Move the connection code to another worker thread and access the GUI as needed using `UiApplication.invokeLater` or `UiApplication.invokeAndWait` to wrap your GUI-related code inside the parameter Runnables. Or either use `synchronized(application.getEventLock()`.

That said, the fact that you are not reading data in small files only could be caused by this line:

```
dis.readFully(b);
```

<strike>Maybe you need to flush the stream.</strike> This call will block until `b.length` bytes are available. Check before that file is readable with `fconn.isReadable`.

UPDATE:
You can try also `IoUtilities.streamToBytes(dis)`, but do not use it with big files or you can get an out-of-memory error.

Comment: well the reason all my code is bundled up here is because this is a simple testapp to test the functionality of an api I am working with. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try this out right away.

Comment: Flush what? How? Why? `InputStreams` don't have a flush method.

Comment: You are right. I've updated answer. Have a try at IOUtilities method. You could also add some println sentences to spot where the problem is.